# highly discontinuous vs discontinuous

Tags: functions

$l_0$-norm of a vector **x** denoted by $||$**x**$||_0$ is a function that counts the non-zero entries in this vector. This function has infinite points of discontinuity in its domain.

In a book [1-page 48], I read that the $l_0$-norm is highly discontinuous. But I could not find the difference of a highly discontinuous and discontinuous function. What is the difference of them? What "highly" means in highly discontinuous?

[1] M. Elad, Sparse and Redundant Representations, Springer New York, 2010.

Comment: I think you should give the concrete reference to where you read that.

Comment: I think you should state what the $l_0$ norm is, and the def'n of highly discontinuous. No one knows all of the terminology.

Comment: "Discontinuous" is essentially a standard term and means there is at least one point in the domain at which the function is not continuous. "Highly discontinuous" is not a standard term, and depending on the situation it could mean infinitely many discontinuities or a dense set of discontinuities, or it could mean the discontinuities themselves are rather extreme (such as lim-inf = $-\infty$ and lim-sup = $+\infty$ at the discontinuity points).

Comment: The $L^0$ norm has more than one point of discontinuity: it is discontinuous when any component of $\mathbf x$ is zero. Perhaps the authors call it "highly discontinuous" because those points are exactly the ones they are interested in (for example, if you want to compute sparse solutions).